# Autocomplete a textbox created inside the PHP tags

Tags: php, jquery

```
echo "<table width='234' border='1'>";
while(strtotime($USA_START) <= strtotime($USA_END)) 
{

    $day_num = date('d', strtotime($USA_START));
    $day_name = date('l', strtotime($USA_START));
    echo "<tr><td>$day_num </td><td> $USA_START</td> <td> $day_name</td><td><input type='text'  name='txtRep[]'  ></td></tr>";
    $USA_START = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($USA_START)));
}

echo "</table>";
```

I have above php code which has a loop and create a textbox for each record in a line.

When it is outside the php codes (that means when it is in pure html codes) I have successfully auto completed the below textbox.

```
<td><input type='text' name='txtRep[]'  ></td>
```

with JQuery. But when I created this inside PHP tags by echoing the textbox, the auto complete process does not work?

Can anybody suggest an approach or is this impossible?

Here is the PHP code for auto complete

```
<?php
require_once "../DCR/connection/conn.php";
$q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
if (!$q) return;

$query = "select * from REPPROF where REPTYPE='Mrep' and (REPNAME like '%".strtoupper($q)."%' or REPCODE like '%".strtoupper($q)."%')"; 

$statement = oci_parse ($connection, $query);
oci_execute ($statement);

while ($row = oci_fetch_array ($statement, OCI_BOTH)){  

    $txt1=$row['REPCODE'];
    $txt2=$row['REPNAME'];  

$B=$txt1.'~'.$txt2;                     

echo "$B\n";

    //echo  $query;                 
}
oci_close($connection);
?>
```

and Jquery

```
$().ready(function() {  
$("#txtMedRep").autocomplete("Mrep_auto_complete.php", {    width: 200,max: 20,selectFirst: false});
});
```

Comment: it's in a loop. How many times is the box getting created? Each box the loop creates will have the same ID attribute. This is invalid HTML, IDs must be unique. Fix this and then see if you still have a problem. Might be useful to show how you're adding the autocomplete functionality as well

Comment: Additionally, you could change it so your PHP loop has a 'value' for auto-completion: <input type='text' name='txtMedRep' id='txtMedRep' value='.$some_sort_of_value.'></td> -- Or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: check the html output on the page.. if the syntax generated is proper or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've edited the question, there's now no longer element with ID "txtMedRep". So the Javascript will not add the autocomplete to anything.

Define your textbox with a class, something like:

```
<input type='text'  name='txtRep[]'  class='autocomplete'>
```

Then change your autocomplete definition to:

```
$().ready(function() {  
  $(".autocomplete").autocomplete("Mrep_auto_complete.php", { width: 200,max: 20,selectFirst: false});
});
```

This will cause it to add the autocomplete functionality to all elements which have the "autocomplete" class.

Comment: Nice one ..... It works .A full basket of fruits for u :)


So what happens if I got another textbox to autocomplete towns in same way .

$().ready(function() { 
$("#txtTown").autocomplete("town_auto_complete.php", { width: 200,max: 20,selectFirst: false});
});

<input type='text'  name='txtRep[]'  class='autocomplete'>
<input type='text'  name='txtTown[]'  class='autocomplete'>

How to call two autocomplete functions relevantly to each textbox ?

Comment: just give the elements a different class... e.g. "autocomplete-towns". So `$(".autocomplete").autocomplete("Mrep_auto_complete.php", { width: 200,max: 20,selectFirst: false}); $(".autocomplete-towns").autocomplete("town_auto_complete.php", { width: 200,max: 20,selectFirst: false}); });` and ` <input type='text' name='txtRep[]' class='autocomplete'>` and `<input type='text' name='txtTown[]' class='autocomplete-towns'>`

Comment: lovely .. fulfilled

Comment: @code_Finder that's great. if it's helped you please mark as the accepted answer, thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in PHP (anymore). It will output names for the inputs just fine. But JQuery tries to attach to an unknown HTML element id. `$("#txtMedRep")` does not exist anymore (after some edits you made).

To fix it, try:

```
$().ready(function() {  
    $("input").autocomplete("Mrep_auto_complete.php", {    width: 200,max: 20,selectFirst: false});
});
```

Which is off course ALL inputs, but outputting a class on these inputs that is easily fixed

Comment: Just plz explain ... what does the $("input"). do here ??
How do I complete another textbox together in the same loop?